# Set accurately Assets in Xcode 7 for all iPhone devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7, uiimageasset

I am looking for best solution for setting image assets in Xcode 7, I googled and found many threads those are discussing on setting on image assets.
Here below is what I found

- 1x images are for the original iPhone through the 3GS - 'standard'
  resolution devices (3.5" screens)
- 2x images are for the iPhone 4 and 4S (3.5" Retina screens) and are
  also used for the iPhone 6.
- Retina 4 2x are for the iPhone 5 and 5s (4" Retina screens)
- 3x images are for the new iPhone 6+ (5.5" super-Retina [3x] screen)

as also shown in attached image.[image: Facebook Image]

But there is no more Retina-4 option so I am confuse how to set accurately in below attached image.[image: Xcode 7 Image Assets]

1x: is for non retina

2x: is for retina (confuse here either for iPhone 4 Retina, 5 Retina or 6)

3x: is for 6 plus.

Correct me if I am wrong. Looking for clarification.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get all the information regarding Asset from top to bottom on this link.

[About Asset Catalogs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/Recipe.html)

According to your Question you can find information in proper detail on this link [iosdesign-guidelines](https://designcode.io/iosdesign-guidelines)

> Developers work with point values, so it is important to understand
>   the difference with **pixels**. When the iPhone was first introduced, the
>   two units were the same: 1pt equals 1px. Then when retina screens came
>   along, 1pt became 2px. So think of points as the values in the
>   original iPhone, and pixels as the real values depending on the pixel
>   density (**iPhone 4,5,6 = @2x**, **iPhone 6 Plus = @3x**).

Check here for resolution [ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome . Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% clear on the question, here are the sizes: http://makeappicon.com/ios8icon

I often do the following:

1. Look for the following in your file:

[image: Location]

2. Then I have the following, with multiple sizes of the same image, named to match their respective size:

[image: Images to have]

3. The Contents.json then has the following:

   ```
   "images" : [
       {
         "size" : "29x29",
         "idiom" : "iphone",
         "filename" : "icon-58.png",
         "scale" : "2x"
       },
       {
         "size" : "29x29",
         "idiom" : "iphone",
         "filename" : "icon-87.png",
         "scale" : "3x"
       },
       {
         "size" : "40x40",
         "idiom" : "iphone",
         "filename" : "icon-80.png",
         "scale" : "2x"
       },
       {
         "size" : "40x40",
         "idiom" : "iphone",
         "filename" : "icon-120.png",
         "scale" : "3x"
       },
       {
         "size" : "60x60",
         "idiom" : "iphone",
         "filename" : "icon-121.png",
         "scale" : "2x"
       },
       {
         "size" : "60x60",
         "idiom" : "iphone",
         "filename" : "icon-180.png",
         "scale" : "3x"
        }
     ],
     "info" : {
       "version" : 1,
       "author" : "xcode"
     }
   }
   ```
4. Then check your assets in Xcode

[image: Where to look]

If you have done everything correctly, they should all be filled:

[image: All Icons filled]

If a size is not correct, the image will not be in it's respective spot.

Comment: Thanks @App Dev Guy, icon "icon-58.png" is for iPhone 4,5 and 6 ? and "icon-87.png" is for iPhone 6plus. Kindly correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: @Aleem Yes, it is. I hope my post helped, as well as how to implement icons correctly.